# Please solve following query related to SQL

Tags: sql

My table contains ID and ID1

```
ID  ID1
5   8
6   9
7   1
```

Now The result set should like This

```
ID  ID1
8   5
9   6
1   7
```

Comment: Could you format this so its understandable and elaborate a bit more on *why* you wan't exactly that result you describe?

Comment: @King Skippus: you beat me to the edit :)

Comment: I'm not saying this is worth downvoting, or closing, but is this a homework question?

Answer (score 2):

```
select ID ID1, ID1 ID from tablename;
```

Comment: this means that ID1 will be the alias for ID and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID1 as 'ID'
     , ID  as 'ID1'
FROM   <your table name>
```

If I understand you correctly it looks like you want to switch the field names.

Answer (score 1):

```
ID  ID1
5   8
6   9
7   1
```

As you have mention you just want ID1 column first then ID so in select statement
  you have to specify ID1 column first,then ID like this.

```
  SELECT ID1 'ID',ID 'ID1' FROM tablename;
```

so in above statement `'ID' is alias for ID1` and '`ID1' is alias for ID`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the order of the columns in the output you can change it after the SELECT keyword:

```
SELECT a, b FROM ...
SELECT b, a FROM ...
```

The first query will have column a first, the second query will have column b first

Comment: Also needs to alias each column as the other for some unknown reason.